# How could I redefine a subroutine and keep the old one too?

Tags: perl, symbols, redefinition

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

```
sub first {
    print "this is original first";
}

*original_first = \&first;

sub first {
    print "this is first redefined";
}

original_first(); # i expect this to print "this is original first"
first() # i expect this to print "this is first redefined"
```

I thought that by saving the symbol for `first`, I'd be able to later call the original subroutine ( under the name `original_first` ) and to also be able to call `first`, and get the one redefined. However, if I call the `original_first`, I still get the "this is first redefined". What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work as you expect:

```
sub first {
    print "this is original first";
}

*original_first = \&first;

*first = sub {
    print "this is first redefined";
};
```

Comment: Is it possible, when you redefine the `first` symbol, to affect only the code part?

Comment: an assignment of a coderef (generated by sub{...}) to a typeglob will only replace the CODE entry in the glob.  any other datatypes in the glob will not change

Comment: You can also use `local *first = sub {...};` to replace function within specific block only.

Answer (score 9):

in your code, Perl interprets both sub declarations similar to this:

```
BEGIN {
    *first = sub { ... }
}
```

so both assignments to `&first` end up happening before saving the copy and calling the routines.  the fix is to make the second declaration into a runtime assignment:

```
sub first {
    print "this is original first";
}

*original_first = \&first;

*first = sub {print "this is first redefined"};

original_first(); # prints "this is original first"
first();          # prints "this is first redefined"
```

Comment: citation needed for the `sub {}` -> `BEGIN { *... }` behaviour you describe.

Comment: i am inferring the above from the following explanation from perlmod:  Subroutine definitions (and declarations, for that matter) need not necessarily be situated in the package whose symbol table they occupy. You can define a subroutine outside its package by explicitly qualifying the name of the subroutine:

   1. package main;
   2. sub Some_package::foo { ... } # &foo defined in Some_package

This is just a shorthand for a typeglob assignment at compile time:

   1. BEGIN { *Some_package::foo = sub { ... } }

Answer (score 1):

See the [Hook::LexWrap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Hook-Lexwrap) module, which can handle all of that for you. If you don't want to use the module, just look at the source, which shows you exactly how to do it.